# Box sizing all elements within div

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, box-sizing

I'm using the bootstrap 4.0 minified css on an application site I want to inject over the top of another site.

Here is the file: http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.min.css

The issue I'm having is the following styling is affecting the site sitting behind my application because of these styles:

```
*,
:after,
:before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

I've tried to modify the CSS so it targets only everything within my wrapping div like so:

```
.prefix-wrapper * {
        -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
        box-sizing: inherit;
    }
```

This didn't work - any ideas?

Comment: It has to inherit someting different...right? So where is it supposed to inherit it from?

Comment: .prefix-wrapper like I've put in the code example?

Comment: Yes...but what have you set on the `prefix-wrapper`?

Comment: The code is above in my question

Comment: Then it's not logical...if you don't **change** the box-sizing on the parent, the children can't inherit it.

Comment: Right now I understand, so my prefix styling needs to have "border-box" instead of inherit, this makes sense.

Comment: Depending on what the original box-sizing was, then yes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Bootstap 4 but the current "thinking" is that the box-sizing 'reset' is formed like so:

```
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

So, if you wish to use,

```
.prefix-wrapper * {
        -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
        box-sizing: inherit;
    }
```

...you *first* have to change the box-sizing property on the parent to something different.

So something like:

```
.prefix-wrapper {
        -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
        box-sizing: content-box;
    }
```

[**Inheriting box-sizing @ CSS-Tricks**](https://css-tricks.com/inheriting-box-sizing-probably-slightly-better-best-practice/)